# hosting heterogeneous yang schemas at arbitrary locations

Tags: ietf-netmod-yang

I have this need to be able to navigate heterogeneous schema trees from a known point in the overall schema tree.

say, I define a container node /middleware:devices

and when I learn the device schemas of various devices , want to hook/host those
schemas under the above container

```
/middleware:devices/vendor1:device/stuff1 
/middleware:devices/vendor2:device/stuff2
/middleware:devices/abstract:device/stuff3
```

etc.

I don't want to change my schema and use a uses (with the device schemas) clause
nor can I expect the device schemas augment my container. 
So, neither my yang file knows about the device schemas nor those device schemas know my yang schema.

is there anything in the yang world meant to address this situation ? I see that there is discussion on 'mount'. Is that what it is ? or is there something else or no such facility exist at all ? 
thanks

Comment: I believe your case is similar to the example in [Appendix C](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-netmod-schema-mount-03#appendix-C) of YANG Schema Mount draft. It is probably what you have described - it allows you to define an `anydata` node with well defined contents (`stuff` would be an `anydata` node in your case).